# Auto fill not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on my code and I have this to filter rows and insert a formula in the first filter row. with that formula I want it to fill down, but it only insert the formula in the first filtered row and doesn't fill down.

```
Sub Cal()
dim LastRow as long
With Worksheets("Data")
.Range("$A$1:$AI$80000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "Actual"
.Range("$A$1:$AI$80000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="2018"
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 35).Select 'SELECTS THE FIRST cell in A after deleting
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-12]:RC[-1])"
.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 35).Select
Selection.FillDown
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you using `AutoFill`?

Comment: Auto fill will be used at the active cell.

Comment: Have yo tried `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("$A$1:$AI$80000")` ??

Comment: The active cell after filtering that I select is in AI and the first row after filtering is AI2345. that cell gets the formula but it dosnt fill the formula down to the end of the filtered rows.

Comment: I would be careful using autofill if the row numbers are not consecutive. After filtering, where row numbers are not consecutive, I've filled in **every** row from first row used to last row used !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like below, instead of .FillDown, specify the range for the last column of visible data, and offset to the next column to enter the formula in there:

```
Sub Cal()
Dim LastRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("$A$1:$AI$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Actual"
        .Range("$A$1:$AI$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="2018"
        'filter according to values specified
        Set fltrdrng = .Range("$AI$2:$AI$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'set the range of visible data on last column with data on your data-set
        fltrdrng.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-12]:RC[-1])"
        'add the formula to the adjacent column by offsetting
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.  Autofilling is very dangerous with filtered data.  This gets the activecell address and then creates the last cell address(row 80000 from your code), and then adds the formula to every cell in the range that is visible.

```
Start = ActiveCell.address
arow = ActiveCell.Row
alen = Len(arow)
lcell = Left(Start, Len(Start) - alen) & "80000"
Range(Start & ":" & lcell).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=SUM(RC[-12]:RC[-1])"
```